# Unable to send email using smtp in c#

Tags: c#, smtp

I'd like my system to send email when a button is clicked, I however keep getting a problem at smtp.send(message) everytime, there is no error or anything, it just kind of freezes although its still running. I have written 4 attempts and all are unsuccessful.

**1st attempt:**

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

    mail.From = new MailAddress("robinx0852@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("robinx0852@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
    mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

    SmtpServer.Port = 25;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    MessageBox.Show("Email sent successfully");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

**2nd attempt:**

```
try
{
    //string s = $"User {edtID} has failed to login";

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add("robinx0852@gmail.com");
    message.Subject = "Employee login failure";
    message.From = new MailAddress("armeepatel@gmail.com");
    message.Body = "Hello";
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.saix.net");
    smtp.Send(message);
    MessageBox.Show("mail Sent");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com", "ME"));
mailMessage.Subject = "Some Subject";
mailMessage.Body = "Test";
smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

**3rd attempt:**

```
// string s = $"User {edtID} has failed to login";
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
mail.To.Add("mymail@gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("hotelfrontdesk@testhotel.com");
mail.Subject = "Employee login failure";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = "Hello";
SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.saix.net";
SmtpServer.Port = 25;
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
try
{

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Inner: " + ex.InnerException);

}
```

**4th attempt:**

```
var sysLogin = "yourlogin@gmail.com";
var sysPass = "y0urP@ss";
var sysAddress = new MailAddress(sysLogin, "Message from me!");

var receiverAddress = new MailAddress("mymail#gmail.com");

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",   //gmail example
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = false,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sysLogin, sysPass)
};


using (var message = new MailMessage(sysAddress, receiverAddress) { Subject = "Some subject", Body = "Some text" })
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
MessageBox.Show("Success");
```

Comment: If your code is all commented out, how do you expect it to do anything? How do you "send email using SQL" if you're using `SmtpClient`? Why do you call an instance of an `SmtpClient` an `SmtpServer`? That seems backwards.

Comment: Its all commented out because i was trying each individual one alone, it runs through everything but fails at smtp.Send(message);

Comment: Have a look at those: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you include the exception message with each attempt.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn He said that he doesnt get exceptions his code just freezes at a line.

Comment: @RandRandom I suspect this is a web app, and the line where it freezes is actually the MessageBox.Show() line, because it's waiting for someone to click the OK button on a Message Box no one can see.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I guess we will never know, we are kinda still waiting for the clarification what SQL has anything to do with his question. :)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i believe this is part of the sql query, i'm really not sure though because i only just started with trying to implement this now, if its not sql then i apologise.

Comment: @RandRandom its actually a proper app, not a web app that i'm trying to implement this in

Comment: @Armee SQL has nothing to do with this. Even if you are sending messages based on SQL results, that's irrelevant to the fact that smtp connection is not opening. You would have that problem with our without SQL involved.

Comment: One other suggestion: try setting a smaller value for the Timeout property. That might let the code proceed so you can view the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? It seems all of your attempts had SSL+25, or 587+NoSSL. SSL should be with port 587.

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
{
                Port = 587,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Myemail@gmail.com", "MyPassword")
};
```

Comment: Additionally, gmail is very picky about SMTP access now. This can only work if "Less Secure Apps" are enabled (if you're not using two-factor auth), or if you're using an app-specific password (if you are using two-factor auth).

Answer (score 1):

I once had an issue where my email client would freeze on sending a mail when using stmp settings for gmail. I then had to create an App Password in Gmail Account settings and use that app-password in the stmp settings to make my client work. Try this, hope it fixes the freeze issue

1. Go To https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
2. Select and App[Custom, if any] , Device [Custom, if any] and then Click on Generate.
3. A password will be generated something like this : kxyo gmnz dais wcau
4. Use this app-password instead of the password you are using right now in stmp settings.

Comment: Thank you Rahul. Could you by any chance give me directions on how to implement this?

Comment: The need for this depends on whether or not you've enabled Two-Factor Authentication. If you do have 2FA, you'll need this app-specific password. If you're not using 2FA, you instead need to enable "Less Secure Apps", or update your C# code to use OAuth (not trivial).

Comment: @Armee i've updated my answer, But my solution requires your account to have two-step verification enabled. Then only this will work